# understanding why/how my accounts got locked out after libpam-systemd update

Tags: password, pam

Some of my accounts are locked out after an updated of Ubuntu 20.04 with the latest `libpam-systemd` package. I'm trying to understand why some accounts are locked out and others not, since the `common-auth` rule is applied to all users. Details below.

My system has a few users (mine included) that have no sudo privileges. I have a separate admin user that's blocked from ssh login in `sshd_config` as a security measure. All users connect to this machine via ssh, so I planned to have an extra security over logins. I have set the following rule in `common-auth` to restrict the number of login attempts:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    required                        pam_deny.so
auth    required    pam_tally2.so       onerr=fail deny=3 unlock_time=21600
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
```

So, the crash: After logging in to my regular account via ssh, I `sudo -`'ed to the admin account to perform  `apt update`. A few updates involved systemd, e.g., libpam-systemd, which prompted the question about overriding or not the `common-*` changes, which I chose not in order to keep the changes above. Finally, a reboot was needed, and after that, voilà, accounts locked. Since I typed the correct password for my regular account via ssh, I assume that the authentication process is not entirely working with PAM.

The 2 accounts used to perform the update (mine via ssh plus the admin one with `su -`) got locked out after failed logins (although I have typed the correct password). Oddly, the other accounts are still allowed to login via ssh. From one of them I tried to `su -` to my account or the admin one, but no success: *Account locked due to X failed logins*.

Anyways, I've read other [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/35548/console-user-locked-out-pam-problems?newreg=1b7f48323eec4bf6a01f80f06448bf27) warning about changes in `common-*` that would lead to a permanent lock, although my changes are very simple. The 2 questions that remains are:

1 - Why keeping the changes of `common-*` lead to PAM locking my accounts? My `common-auth` seems pretty simple to lead to a PAM auth confusion.

2 - Why are the 2 active accounts locked and the others not?

Comment: I got access after waiting the penalty time. It seems that the libpam update triggered the penalty for the active connections.